# Return redirect en get_context_data devuelve "context must be a dict rather than HttpResponseRedirect"

Tags: python, django

En el else, necesito redirigir a una url, pero devuelve el siguiente error, que no comprendo el motivo. ¿Qué ocurre?

**Error:**

```
context must be a dict rather than HttpResponseRedirect.
```

**View:**

```
class testFilterByModalityAndByUserView(ListView):
    model = TestQuestion
    template_name = 'test/question.html'
    urlReturn = 'test_app:test'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            ...
       else:
            return redirect('users_app:user-login')
```

Answer (score 1):

Estas abordando de forma equivocada el redireccionamiento en Django, este no se puede realizar dentro de el método get_context_data() en la [Vistas Basada en Clase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/), el objetivo de este método es agregar datos al contexto de la vista, para tu caso el modelo es TestQuestion, por lo que podrías agregar datos sobre otro modelo dentro de la vista.

Si lo que querés es redireccionar a un usuario hacia la vista de ingreso al sistema existen varias formas de abordarlo. Para tu caso lo más recomendable es utilizar el Mixin que provee el paquete Auth en Django llamado [LoginRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin), de la siguiente forma:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class testFilterByModalityAndByUserView(ListView):
    model = TestQuestion
    template_name = 'test/question.html'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       ...
```

Otra opción es hacer to propia implementación de los métodos [dispatch()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch), get() y/o post() de la vista, sin embargo esto es justamente lo que hace el [LoginRequiredMixin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py).

Finalmente y si sos nuevo en Django podría ser bueno hacer Vistas Basadas en Funciones, ya que descomponen todo el funcionamiento de la vista y sirven para aprender más sobre el funcionamiento interno de Django.